# Dimension of subspace of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $V$ is the vector space polynomial with real coefficients, grade $\leq3$. Let $W$ be the subspace of all polynomials $p(x)$ in $V$ such that $p(0) = p(1) =
p(-1) = 0$.

Then what is $\dim V + \dim W$?

I think the $\dim V =4$ and $\dim W=2$, I will be very grateful to you if you help me.

Comment: Monomials are linearly independent so dim(V) is 4. dim(W) is 1 because the form of polynomials is a(x-1)(x)(x+1)

Comment: I get it. Thanks a lot.